# The Tcp Server is unware of the broken link when data interaction is frequently high

Tags: linux, tcpserver

I meet a situation that one machine is A, as a TCP server, which accept the other machine to connect,
and the other machine is B, as a TCP client.
There is no heartbeat protocol for A and B, when two sides are communication.

The A server uses accept to accept client and uses select to wait for the read events from client.
And A server is enabled of tcp keepalive function, with keepidle=1, keepcnt=3, keepintvl=1.

I test follwing abnormal cases for how to close the socket safely.

1.If B is active to close the socket, the A will get read events, and the server read action returns error.
2.If A and B remained silent, the keepalive will work ok. If the cable is unpluged, the server select will get read events and read error.

3.If A and B remained data interaction,the cable is unpluged at the same time. The server select returns 0 and no read event last for a long time(sometimes a half of an hour). why ? I check the packet using wireshark, no keepalive packet is found.

By the way, I have checked some useful message that the prioriy of rertransmission packet is higher than keepalive packet, sometimes keepalive is no chance to probe.

**I think that if has any way to let application-level codes to send signal to kernel to let the retransmission packet to be discard?**

thanks a lot.